# Start/Play Embedded (iframe) youtube video on click of an mp4 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe, youtube

I am trying to embed a youtube video onto my html page on the click of an mp4 video. I am wondering if this is possible to do?

I have copied my current code below but it won't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#video1").on('click', function() {
    var video = '<iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="' + $(this).attr('data-video') + '"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $(this).replaceWith(video);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="embed-container">
  <video autoplay muted loop id="play" preload="auto">
    <source id="video1" src="/media/wysiwyg/cms/halloween/2017/desktop/halloween.mp4" type='video/mp4' data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KJ2dyKGLRMo?autoplay=1">
    <source id="video1" src="/media/wysiwyg/cms/halloween/2017/desktop/halloween.webm" type='video/webm' data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KJ2dyKGLRMo?autoplay=1">
  </video>
</div>
```

P.S. no credit to this youtube video I've used, currently just using it as an example

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I worked it out!

Added the id to the div which had the same class as my embed-container

```
<div id="video1" class="embed-container" data-video="https://www.youtube.com">
  <video autoplay muted loop id="play" preload="auto">
    <source  src="/media/wysiwyg/cms/halloween/2017/desktop/halloween.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source  src="/media/wysiwyg/cms/halloween/2017/desktop/halloween.webm" type='video/webm'>
  </video>
</div>
```